# Programmatically put an image into the form which is not active?

Tags: c#, winforms

I want programmatically put an image into the form which is not active.

```
Image myImage = new Image();
gfx = Form.ActiveForm.CreateGraphics();
gfx.DrawImage(myImage, 0,0);
```

It's will be working perfectly only if the form is active, but it's make no sense when the form is not active, just returns me an error:

> In an instance of an object reference not set to an object.

how to handle the form which is not active in my application and put a picture to it?

**upd** [1](http://www.imagesocket.com/photos/guest/2503780)

I did instance, and turned on DoubleBuffered property (true) but nothing happens:

```
Form1 form = new Form1();
gfx = form.CreateGraphics();
gfx.DrawImage(bmp, 0, 0);
```

**upd** 2 More Source, it's my added class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Drawing.Printing;

namespace testimg
{
    class doimg
    {

        public void picture()
        {

            // some staffs to get a picture, so it's in bmp object now.

            gfx = this. // watch picture below
            gfx.DrawImage(bmp, 0, 0);

            // I tried to use PictureBox, but it's the same issue (I can't handle it on a form)
            PictureBox pb = new PictureBox();
            pb.CreateGraphics();
            pb.DrawToBitmap(bmp,pb.ClientRectangle);

        }

    }
}
```

and a picture for the **Arif Eqbal** solution: [no graph methods for this (pic)](http://www.imagesocket.com/photos/guest/2503780)

**upd** 3

The full source what I have (timer is on a 10 sec)

**Form1.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace testimg
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            doimg pic = new doimg();

            pic.picture();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Enabled = true;
        }
     }
}
```

**doimg.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Drawing.Printing;


namespace testimg
{
    class doimg
    {

        public void picture()
        {

            // some staffs to get a picture, so it's in bmp object now.
            Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(200, 200,    System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
            Graphics gfx = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
            gfx = Form1.ActiveForm.CreateGraphics(); // works well with active form
            gfx.DrawImage(bmp, 0, 0);


        }


     }
}
```

and whole archive with project http://www.filedropper.com/testimg

as you can see all running well while the program is active. Still need help.

Comment: Is the second form visible not minimized but not active ? also is first form active?

Comment: I have a single form, yes, sometimes it's can be minimized and not active, but working aswell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of the problem is that when you are setting your bitmap the Form is not updating, expecially if it is minimized or doesn't have focus. You also have the issue that since it is not being set in the Paint Event Handler you have no retention of the Image.  Try something like this, Note the `Invalidate` call and the Timer was set for 10,000 ms. This is a variation of @LarsTech's answer if you are working with multiple Forms his is the way to go.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Bitmap myImage;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        myImage = new Bitmap("Your Image Name Here");
        Invalidate();

    }

    private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {

        if (myImage != null)
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(myImage,0,0);

    }


}
```

---

Modifed my Example to work with the OP's structure:

My original example does work when the form does not have focus. Your main problem with the error is using `Form1.ActiveForm` when it is not the active form, it will return null which is causing your error. Use the Forms Paint Event and Invalidate the Form to insure that the Image is painted.

**Form1.cs**

```
namespace testimg
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Bitmap myImage;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            myImage = doimg.picture();
            Invalidate();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Enabled = true;
        }

        private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            if (myImage != null)
                e.Graphics.DrawImage(myImage,0,0);
        }
    }
}
```

**doimg.cs**

```
namespace testimg
{
    static class  doimg
    {
        static Color[] clr = new Color[] { Color.Red, Color.Blue, Color.Black, Color.Violet, Color.Wheat };
        static  int count = 0;
        static  public Bitmap picture()
        {

            // some staffs to get a picture, so it's in bmp object now.
            Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(200, 200, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

            // Added some drawing to bitmap to test functionality
            Graphics gfx = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
            gfx.FillEllipse(new SolidBrush(clr[count]),new Rectangle(0,0,199,199));

            gfx.Dispose();

            if (count >= 4)
                count = 0;
            else
                count += 1;

            return bmp;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: see upd 3 pls I added more overview.

Comment: when I'm running now there is no any red pixels on the form, how to use it? But no errors also.

Comment: @VictorCzechov Changed the example to use graphics to draw on bitmap

Comment: @VictorCzechov The pixels are drawm on the form in the Form Paint event, make sure you attach the handler to the Forms Paint event through the Property Editor

Comment: yeah, thanks, it's realy was a Paint event problem, now it works well!

Answer (score 2):

On your Form2, try to set it up like this:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form {

  public Image MyImage { get; set; }

  public Form2() {
    InitializeComponent();
  }

  protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e) {
    if (MyImage != null) {
      e.Graphics.DrawImage(MyImage, 0, 0);
    }
    base.OnPaint(e);
  }
}
```

Then from your active form, you can call the other form to draw itself:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {
  Form2 f2 = new Form2();

  public Form1() {
    InitializeComponent();
    f2.Show();
  }

  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    f2.MyImage = myImage;
    f2.Invalidate();
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't have any other forms, just not active application which is loading images by the timer (for example).

Answer (score 1):

You have to create an instance of your form.. regardless of whether it's visible and active.

Example:

```
Image myImage = new Image(); // load image
MyForm form = new MyForm();
gfx = form.CreateGraphics();
gfx.DrawImage(myImage, 0, 0);
```

Then you will be able to call form.Show() when you want to show the form.

(Note, you'll probably also have to set DoubleBackBuffer on the form to true.

Comment: actually my form is not hidden, just not active.

Answer (score 0):

I think I can make a sense of it...is it that your code to Get the instance of the form and draw on it run on a timer? And your application has just one form? And you run into issues when the Application is not Active?

If Yes then replace the line

```
Form.ActiveForm.CreateGraphics();
```

with

```
this.CreateGraphics();
```

Form.ActiveForm gives the reference of the currently Active Form for the Application, if you write this code on say a Button click you are bound to get the name of the Form on which the Button was clicked. However, if the code is on a timer it might give the instance of the Active form or Null if the entire application is not Active.

As you have mentioned in one of the comments that you do not have any other form, it appears that your application has just one form and this code is running on the only form in the app so this.CreateGraphics should suffice. However, if your application has more than one form then Form.ActiveForm is a legitimate code but you need to take care of the scenario when no form is active i.e. the application itself is not active.

EDIT:

I think you need to pass the instance of the Form on which you want to draw to this class. Make a properry and set the property value to the instance of the form, you might pass it in the constructor as well...using Form.ActiveForm was not a bad idea here but for 2 reasons, tomorrow if you had more than one form in your app it will draw randomly on whicheever is active, second as in your current case if the app is not active you will not get hold of the instance...since you have only one form in your app I suppose you would be creating the instance of this Class on the form so may be you can add a property

```
public Form ParentForm { get; set; }
```

in the class and set it as

```
myClassObject.ParentForm = this;
```

on the form when you create an instance of this class and then say

```
ParentForm.CreateGraphics
```

in the class

Comment: Yes, u make sense, but I used added class for this, and refference to **this** will not help.

Comment: What do you mean "Added Class" can you show how you create the form on which this needs to be drawn...you should have the access to the instance of the form on your timer event and use that instance instead of "this".

Comment: still dont have a clue how to apply your suggestions. Pls. see upd 3.

Comment: @VictorCzechov I hope you understood the issue now, you had 2 problems...one your class did not have a reference to the control (or form) on which it needed to draw, second, even if you get that it will draw only when the timer ticked...painting does not work that way, every time your form recovers from a situation where it is obscured by something like another window coming over it or it got minimized etc. it will again want to paint everything but your code will paint only on timer tick...so the best place to draw is paint event...see solution given by others like Mark Hall for that...